# raspberry pi 4 is constantly rebooting after stalled upgrade

Tags: pi-4, update, raspberry-pi-os, reboot

I had `sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade`'ed my raspberry pi 4 with raspberry OS. The upgrade process stalled while unpacking. or at least I thought it did. nothing happened for minutes while unpacking and the led stoped flashing. After a while I pulled the plug. Now its constantly rebooting. I have a home assistant configuration on there, but I cant log in via SSH anymore.

Can I fix this? Or at least save my HA & node red configs that ran in docker?

edit: I have a NOOBS partition `RECOVERY`.

I stuck the SD Card in my mac, bot it only shows the `RECOVERY` and `boot` partition

Comment: I wonder if you add `init=/bin/sh` to your `cmdline.txt` file (in boot) if the Pi would at least boot enough to see what the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interrupting an upgrade may leave your OS in corrupted state.

No one can tell you how to fix it; indeed most of us would just restore from backup or do a fresh install.

In fact there is NO RECOVERY partition on a normal Raspberry Pi OS OS.

If you want to attempt recovery of your data use a fresh SD Card.

---

"how would I attempt recovery with a fresh SDcard?"

You can do this on any **Linux** computer (including the Pi using a fresh install of *Raspberry Pi OS*).

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/102090/8697

**Unfortunately** you have used [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) which makes everything more difficult (including the fact that most recovery hints you may find don't work).

The *boot* and *root* partitions will not be 1 or 2 - you will have to determine these.
`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` should show the partition layout.

This will enable you to recover your *home* directory.
You could try accessing files in the root partition, but this requires more expertise and, frankly, most experienced users wouldn't bother as it is risky and more work than doing a fresh install.

---

"I have a NOOBS recovery partition. Could that help?"
Absolutely NOT - this is to do a fresh install, and would wipe everything. Fortunately NOOBS is now hidden, and only used by some vendors.

Comment: Forgot to mention and updated question. I have a NOOBS recovery partition. Could that help? I do have an image of the SDCARD. But there were crucial changes ever since and I do need to try to get those off the SDCard.

Comment: how would I attempt recovery with a fresh SDcard?